# How to debug which Jenkins build process marked the build as unstable?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a better, methodical way to debug which part of the Jenkins build execution marked the build as unstable? I understand that somewhere in the build process, a publisher decided to mark the build unstable, but I'm finding it difficult to pin-point which publisher.

I'm currently staring at the huge log of the unstable build and comparing it against a successful one, and this manual process is driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a better way than scanning the build logs for problems. I searched in the build logs for the keyword: `UNSTABLE` and found this log snippet:

```
Build step 'Execute shell' changed build result to UNSTABLE
```

This should be enough to know where in the build process was marked unstable, so we can debug from there. Happy debugging!